How to retain Lambda version when update
I'm using SAM to deploy lambda function with version. When redeploy function, I want to publish a new version for it. Please refer to SAM template file.
Function is deployed successfully and new version is created, but previous version (created by SAM) is deleted. I already set DeletionPolicy to Retain.
Seems DeletionPolicy does not work with AWS::Lambda::Version? How to publish a new version but still keep previous version?
Resources:
  MyFunction:
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function

  MyVersion:
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Version
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref MyFunction

